# Where is the about:config box in Thunderbird 17?

Tags: linux, thunderbird, about-config

Where is the about:config box in Thunderbird 17?

I have looked under the Tools Menu and it doesn't seem to be there.

Is there a way to bring up a URL box in Thunderbird I don't know about?

Comment: [This](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/search?esab=a&q=%22config+editor%22) Mozilla Support article on `about:config` says "In Thunderbird 1.5 or later, about:config is accessed via "Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> General -> Config Editor (button)".

Comment: I found it but I am running on Linux and that info is outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Thunderbird 17 the installation defaults don't give a menu at the top, just a set of tool buttons.

On the right side of the Tool bar there is a button with 3 horizontal lines which `'Displays the Application Menu'`. Click on that and select `Preferences -> Preferences`. Select the `Advanced` icon which should be on the right. The first tab is `General` and the `Config Editor` button wlll be on the bottom right.

It is confusing as there is a `General` tab selectable by an icon in the main `Edit Preferences` page. But after you click on the `Advanced` tab on the main `Edit Preferences`there is an additional tab set there, the first of which is `General`. That is where the `Config Editor` is

Comment: A screenshot might help future readers.

Comment: Hm, I don't see a ``Config Editor`` in the ``General`` tab on version 17.

Comment: @Vadi It is confusing as there is a General tab selectable by an icon in the main Edit Preferences page. But after you click on the Advanced tab on the main Edit Preferences there is an additional tab set there, the first of which is General. That is where the Config Editor is

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem just now. The menus are just too deep to get to it.

I just installed the [ViewAbout](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/viewabout/?src=ss) add-on that adds an option to the View menu which allows you to display a number of the different about: windows including about:config.

I was hoping for a button (like the one that was in Toolbar Buttons - no longer compatible), but this is the next best thing.